# Animating a list of points to move away from a given touch location

Tags: android, animation, coordinate-transformation

The animation I am working on achieving is shown below in Figure 1.

1)I have a list containing points on a 2D plane(left) that I am working on animating.

2)A touch is made at location x, and an invisible circle is drawn (middle). I want all of the points contained in that circle to move away from the center (x).

3) A final result example (right)

I am planning on applying this in a way that I can supply any list of points, touch location, numFrames, and force applied on each point per frame. An array of length numFrames is returned, each array item being an already animated list.

Since I plan on implementing this on screen touch, it is possible for another touch to happen while the first touch animation is already in progress. How can I handle these collisions?

Figure 1:
[image: 2D Point Animation]

Comment: i don't understand if you need the implementation of the points going away or just need an advice to handle collisions

Comment: I need both please

Comment: hum i can help you with the first animation but collisions...humm what order of magnitude is the number of points in the view?

Comment: Usually less than 1000 points

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's my 2 cents, you need a list of points, these points should have a position, a velocity and a method to update the position. something like this

```
public class Point {
    public float x, y;
    public boolean isMoving;
    private float dx,dy;

    public Point(float x, float y){
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public boolean move(float maxWidth, float maxHeight){
        if(!isMoving) return false;

        // update the position 
        x += dx;
        y += dy;

        dx /= FRICTION;
        dy /= FRICTION;

        // bounce...?
        if(x < 0 || x > maxWidth){
            dx *= -1;
        }
        if(y < 0 || y > maxHeight){
            dy *= -1;
        }

        if(Math.abs(dx) < MOVEMENT_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(dy) < MOVEMENT_THRESHOLD){
            isMoving = false;
        }

        return isMoving;
    }
}
```

on every touch event you apply a force to every point within the radius and set their velocity

```
for(Point point : mPoints){
    float distance = point.distance(x,y);

    if(distance > mTouchRange) continue;

    float force = (float) Math.pow(1 - (distance / mTouchRange), 2) * mForceFactor;
    float angle = point.angle(x,y);

    point.dx -= Math.cos(angle) * force;
    point.dy -= Math.sin(angle) * force;
    point.isMoving = true;
}
```

then you need an animation that call move on every frame and eventully stops when there are no moving points
you can find the full example [here](https://gist.github.com/lelloman/8763b981c64e7d9c4da548f072e5c5b2)

Comment: This is very good! But i'm not sure it does the collision handling that I need. During the animation the points are incrementally moved. If one touch animation is currently in progress, how could I handle a second touch animation if some points are shared in the animation regions?

Comment: the problem with collision handling is that you need to compute the distance of each point from each other point, that would increase the computation exponentially. one way to avoid this would be to divide your space in tiles and computes collisions only for points located in the same tile or in an adjacent one, this way you increase the complexity of the code by a lot

Comment: I found a simple solution to my problem. And your post helped me reach that conclusion. I was not worried about the individual points colliding, but handling multiple forces on one point.The collision handling can be obtained by having more than one force affect a given point in sequence. The position of the point after the series of force transformations is the same as if the forces had acted at the same time.